# Dynamics CRM 365 - Exporting / importing solution error due to dependencies

Tags: dependencies, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I've developed a solution on a developer Dynamics 365 CRM instance. Actually, it's a trial version which contains all proposed modules during installation. 
Now that I've created my solution, I've exported it as a managed solution and gave it to the customer.
He cannot install it because there are some missing dependencies on his instance, which are the following:
[image]

So it says that on the USER form that I've adding to my solution, there are some dependencies with some other solutions named "Project Service" and "Field Service".

When I go to the form included in my solution, and hit "Show dependencies", it's written that the solution won't be installed on a system that doesn't have a given list of components. Among them, many components (relations, entities, fields) are from the above two solutions.

As I cannot delete the dependent solutions (FieldService and Project Service), how can I resolve these dependencies ?

Comment: I assume Customer CRM instance also Dynamics 365. Trial? 

Can he also install Field Service & Project Service in his instance? Managed solution expects the dependencies in target system. Try adding all the dependency while exporting Managed solution from your trial org.

Or try exporting Unmanaged & give it to him.

Comment: If you have them on your dev environment, you should have them on your destination system. If you are preparing any customizations that you want to share, you should have as clea system as possible, not any system with whatever solutions are there in CRM universe. You should prepare your customizations on clean organization or uninstall FieldServcie, ProjectService from your DEV if you are not using them on on production. Or simply install them on production, if you can. If your DEV is not the same as production, you are simply doing things wrong and asking for a catastrophe at some point

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only add this items from the User entity to the Solution which you has customized, not add the complete Entity. (Also add to your solution only items which you have customized). If you export the solution and the system show's you the missing dependencies, don't select them. But you must be sure that you have not forget something in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

When developing on a trial instance you should remove all the custom modules (such as Field Service etc.) unless they are required and/or available in the Production instance

Also, when building your own customisations never click the <kbd>Add related</kbd> option as this will start a massive import of related components. Instead you should be carefully managing this or you end in situations where your solution contains so much more than is required.

To resolve your issue, I think you need to go through your solution and remove all entities that aren't required. For system entities that you require, only bring in the fields that you have added to CRM and think carefully about the forms and views that you have modified.